# Trouble installing hibernate intellij

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Im using the community edition of Intellij. Hibernate 4.3.1 is downloaded and added to the project structure as a a library (I included everything that I downloaded).

I then attempt to create a SessionFactory however intellij can't find org.hibernate.SessionFactory

Is there something else I need to do besides just adding the hibernate files to the library?

Ive looked on the intellij website and they claim that a hibernate facet is already installed however I can't seem to find the facet.

Where do I need to go from here?

Comment: Define "can't find". Have you imported it? (I'm assuming the library is correctly added to the module already.) How are you creating the session factory?

Comment: I type SessionFactory and it auto completes to org.hibernate.SessionFactory, then it tells me that it cant resolve.
As for the library i downloaded the latest hibernate "package" from their site and included the entire unzipped folder.

Answer (score 0):

To use a hibernate library  you need a configuration file as well (you put it in resources folder). Here's an example:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DBName</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <property name="show_sql">true</property>


        <mapping class="package.ClassName"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Plus you need a jdbc driver installed.